# Mat date start date end date validation angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, angular8, mat-datepicker

I am working on Mat date picker where I have start date and end date where I have one validation that is end date should not be lesser than start date for example

if start date was 12-JAN-2020 end date can be 12-JAN-2020 or greater than this but it can not be 11-JAN-2020.

Currently I was trying with Min MAX but this is not working as expected

I was trying in google & SO not getting correctly

```
   <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDate" placeholder="Choose a date"
          [value]="getData(item2.firstPatientInDate)" [max]="today<item2.lastPatientInDate|| item2.lastPatientInDate == undefined?today:item2.lastPatientInDate" [(ngModel)]="item2.firstPatientInDate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerstart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerend" [max]="today" [min]="item2.firstPatientInDate"   placeholder="Choose a date"
                        [value]="getData(item2.lastPatientInDate)" [(ngModel)]="item2.lastPatientInDate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerend"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>

                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way with reactive forms with custom validation

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
   this.yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   startDate: [''],
   endDate: ['']
   }, {validator: this.checkDates});  
}

checkDates(group: FormGroup) {
   if(group.controls.endDate.value < group.controls.startDate.value) {
   return { notValid:true }
   }
   return null;
}
```

In your Front End

```
<small *ngIf="yourForm.hasError('notValid')">Not valid</small>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find a working sample in below link:

[stackblitz: angular material start-end date sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-start-end-date-sample)

> **TypeScript file**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  startDate = new FormControl(new Date());
  endDate = new FormControl(new Date());
}
```

> **HTML file**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Start Date" [formControl]="startDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="End Date"
   [min]="startDate.value" [formControl]="endDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: basically I am getting value from service to display the date but with your above code that's not working so i tried added value but still got some error

Comment: Please update your question accordingly, from where you assign data to filed and which error you are getting

Comment: I need to get the value from service also so I am using value can you please check this

Comment: I am getting error ```Cannot read property 'value' of undefined```
I have in my form formControlName , what is the difference between it and [formControl]?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way for the customized date range validation

In the HTML code, as you can see on (dateChange) event. I created comparisonStartdateValidator and comparisonEnddateValidator methods for the validation of inputted date range.

HTML file

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label> Covering Start Date </mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="CovStartdate"
      formControlName="covstartdate"
      (dateChange)="comparisonStartdateValidator()"
      required
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="CovStartdate"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #CovStartdate></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="
        formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].hasError('invaliddaterange')
      "
    >
      <strong>Start date cannot be greater than end date</strong>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].hasError('required')"
    >
      Covering Start date is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label> Covering End Date </mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="CovEnddate"
      formControlName="covenddate"
      (dateChange)="comparisonEnddateValidator()"
      required
    />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="CovEnddate"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #CovEnddate></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covenddate'].hasError('invaliddaterange')"
    >
      <strong>End date cannot be earlier than start date</strong>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="formGroup.controls['covenddate'].hasError('required')"
    >
      Covering End date is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[Date range pic initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeciH.png)

TS file

Here in TS code, You may use my customized validations below. The comparisonEnddateValidator method validates the End date while the comparisonStart dateValidator validates the start date.

```
   constructor() { 
     formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
       covenddate: new FormControl(),
       covstartdate: new FormControl()
     });
   }

  comparisonEnddateValidator(): any {
    let ldStartDate = this.formGroup.value['covstartdate'];
    let ldEndDate = this.formGroup.value['covenddate'];

    let startnew = new Date(ldStartDate);
    let endnew = new Date(ldEndDate);
    if (startnew > endnew) {
      return this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': true });
    }

    let oldvalue = startnew;
    this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].reset();
    this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].patchValue(oldvalue);
    return this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': false });
  }

  comparisonStartdateValidator(): any {
    let ldStartDate = this.formGroup.value['covstartdate'];
    let ldEndDate = this.formGroup.value['covenddate'];

    let startnew = new Date(ldStartDate);
    let endnew = new Date(ldEndDate);
    if (startnew > endnew) {
      return this.formGroup.controls['covstartdate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': true });
    }

    let oldvalue = endnew;
    this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].reset();
    this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].patchValue(oldvalue);
    return this.formGroup.controls['covenddate'].setErrors({ 'invaliddaterange': false });
  }
```

[Start date picture error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmPBd.png)
[End date picture error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyVco.png)